# sub query for count number of entries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

- table xb_user has user details
- table xb_order has order details
- table xb_offer has offer details - where user place offer to the order

need output  as order list and total number offer per order

joining below two query

```
select
  order_id, count(offer_order_id) as total_Offer, `offer_user_id` 
from xb_offer 
join xb_orders on order_id=offer_order_id 
group by offer_user_id
```

and

```
SELECT 
  `wo`.`order_id`, `wo`.`order_title`, `woff`.`offer_price`, `wo`.`order_price`,
  `wo`.`order_deadline` , `woff`.`offer_status`,`woff`.`offer_user_id`
FROM `xb_offer` `woff`
JOIN `xb_orders` `wo` ON `wo`.`order_id`=`woff`.`offer_order_id`
JOIN `xb_users` `wu` ON `wu`.`user_id`=`woff`.`offer_user_id`
```

final output

```
order_id | order Title | Total Offer | user id
```

Ex :
[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And note that if a non-aggregated column appears in a SELECT clause then it must also be included in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general thing: In SQL a query result is again a table (consisting of columns and rows). This means you can treat a query like a table, i.e. you can select from it and join it:

```
select ...
from ( <some query here> ) q1
join ( <some other query here> ) q2 on q2.something = q1.something
```

As of MySQL 8 you can also forward-declare these subqueries with `WITH` (which makes it even possible to use the same subquery manyfold in one query without having to copy and paste):

```
with q1 as ( <some query here> )
   , q2 as ( <some other query here> )
select ...
from q1
join q2 on q2.something = q1.something
```

If a query returns only one column and at most one row, it is called scalar. As these queries only select one value, they can be used where you'd normally have a mere value (a constant, and expression or a column). Typical for this are queries that select a value from a row by its id, e.g. the supplier name by their supplier ID, or aggregations, e.g. a maximum date of all orders on a product.

```
select
  a, b, c,
  (select x from t2 where t2.id = t1.t2_id) as d,
  (select min(y) from t3 where t3.t1_id = t1.id) as e
from t1
```

With this latter method you can do this for example:

```
select
  ord.order_id,
  ord.title,
  (select count(*) from xb_offer off2 where off2.order_id = ord.order_id) as total_offer,
  off.offer_user_id
from xb_orders ord
join xb_offer off on off.offer_order_id = ord.order_id
group by ord.order_id, off.offer_user_id
order by ord.order_id, off.offer_user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to count offers per order and user. This translates to `COUNT(order_id)` and `GROUP BY order_id, user_id`.

```
select
  ord.order_id,
  ord.title,
  count(off.offer_order_id) as total_offer,
  off.offer_user_id
from xb_orders ord
left join xb_offer off on off.offer_order_id = ord.order_id
group by ord.order_id, off.offer_user_id
order by ord.order_id, off.offer_user_id;
```

Comment: hi I want it user-based (xb_user table)

Comment: Then your "final output" is incorrect. Please edit your request to show us the columns you really want to have in your output.

Comment: Okay, it is surprising that you have not been able to adapt my query to your needs. After all, you asked for one row per order (`group by ord.order_id`) and now you want one row per order and user (`group by ord.order_id, off.offer_user_id`). Very simple, isnt it? I think you may want to read up a little on aggregation and `GROUP BY` to fully understand the concept.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response....along with group by we need subquery ... as I want total offer per order against user details

Comment: A subquery? Why? We are still counting offers. Does my query result in something different from what you want? If so, in what way? Maybe it's time you show some sample data in your request, so we see what data shall lead to which result set. Ah, wait... Do you mean you don't want to count offers per order and user, but want to have the total offer count for the order, i.e. show for each order the same offer number for each user? What version of MySQL aur you using?

Comment: This is your answer? This looks like the sum of user offers, like I assumed at the end of my last comment. That would be `SUM(count(off.offer_order_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY ord.order_id)` instead of `count(off.offer_order_id)` in standard SQL. MySQL supports this as of version 8.

Comment: thanks buddy it work and if we want for particular use....then???

Comment: Only show a particular user or only count a particular user?

Comment: Only show a particular user? for example user_id = 8

Comment: Okay, as you want to count the offers over *all* users, you could not place a `WHERE` clause or extend the `ON` clause to get that user in my query, because that would remove other users' counts from the aggregation. You would have to place this restriction *after* the aggregation has taken place, i.e. in a `HAVING` clause. Try that. I've also posted another answer with a more general approach that you may like better and find easier to adapt to your needs.